Deriving AC max. average power transfer, where am I wrong?
Starting with the Thevenin equivalent voltage \$V_{th}\$, impedece \$Z_{th}\$ and load impedence \$Z_l\$, the maximum average power transfer seems to be given by \$\frac{|V_{th}|^2}{8R_{th}}\$ but I'm getting a slightly different answer, would appreciate help figuring out where I'm going wrong.
$$
P = 0.5\Re(VI^*) \\
= 0.5\Re(V_{th}(\frac{V_{th}}{Z_L + Z_{th}})^*) \\
= 0.5\Re(V_{th}\frac{V_{th}^*}{(Z_L + Z_{th})^*}) \\
= 0.5\Re(\frac{|V_{th}|^2}{Z_L^* + Z_{th}^*}) \\
$$
And for maximum power transfer \$Z_l = Z_{th}^*\$
$$
= 0.5\Re(\frac{|V_{th}|^2}{2R_{th}}) \\
= \frac{|V_{th}|^2}{4R_{th}} \\
$$
But there has to be an 8 in the denominator? Where did I go wrong? I have checked and the complex conjugate is distributive over addition and multiplication.


But there has to be an 8 in the denominator? Where did I go wrong?

I expect it comes down to how the Thevenin voltage was originally defined. If it was defined as a peak sinewave voltage you need to divide it by \$\sqrt2\$ to get the RMS voltage and, of course, when the RMS is squared you get \$\dfrac{V_{PEAK}}{2}\$. So, that will produce another factor of two in the denominator. You are doing nothing wrong in your math other than possibly making a false assumption: -
How to derive the maximum power transfer theorem using the relation p=v²/R?.

You're a savior, after reading the question you linked to I realized my mistake.My sloppy reasoning, my textbook is calculating the average power through the load while I'm calculating the average power the thevenin source is providing.

The complex conjugate eliminates totally the reactive part of the loop, so you can assume the Thevenin equivalent voltage is connected to the series of resistances Rt and Rload or to 2Rt for max power to the load. The power supplied by the source Vt is Vt * Vt/(2Rt). Half of it is delivered to the load, so your own version is right.
Maybe the original case is different than you presented or it simply is calculated wrong or assumes peak voltage instead of R.M.S. voltage. You and me have used the power formula for the root mean square voltage.

Thanks for the reply, but it isn't clear to me that the power formula in my question uses the RMS voltage and current. See e.g this website. Converting the power formula it lists for peak voltage and current: $0.5I_mV_m \cos(\theta)$ to phasor form gives $0.5\Re(I V)$ which is what I used. What do you think?

I assumed your 0.5 means that half of the power is dissipated inside the Thevenin equivalent and only the other half is delivered to the load. Seemingly you considered also the internally dissipated half as transferred.
